# Pine Script: print a table with 26 last close prices continously

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am new with Pine Script and it's very difficult for me to display continuously a text line with last 26 close prices excepted current candle. Like this for example: 145.235;145.100;146.845;...
Could you help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the table function of pinescript to write on your chart several values.
See [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_table{dot}new](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_table%7Bdot%7Dnew)

Like this working example (from https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Tables.html?highlight=table) :

```
//@version=5
indicator("Price vs MA", "", true)

var string GP1 = "Moving averages"
int     masQtyInput    = input.int(20, "Quantity", minval = 1, maxval = 40, group = GP1, tooltip = "1-40")
int     masStartInput  = input.int(20, "Periods begin at", minval = 2, maxval = 200, group = GP1, tooltip = "2-200")
int     masStepInput   = input.int(20, "Periods increase by", minval = 1, maxval = 100, group = GP1, tooltip = "1-100")

var string GP2 = "Display"
string  tableYposInput = input.string("top", "Panel position", inline = "11", options = ["top", "middle", "bottom"], group = GP2)
string  tableXposInput = input.string("right", "", inline = "11", options = ["left", "center", "right"], group = GP2)
color   bullColorInput = input.color(color.new(color.green, 30), "Bull", inline = "12", group = GP2)
color   bearColorInput = input.color(color.new(color.red, 30), "Bear", inline = "12", group = GP2)
color   neutColorInput = input.color(color.new(color.gray, 30), "Neutral", inline = "12", group = GP2)

var table panel = table.new(tableYposInput + "_" + tableXposInput, 2, masQtyInput + 1)
if barstate.islast
    // Table header.
    table.cell(panel, 0, 0, "MA", bgcolor = neutColorInput)
    table.cell(panel, 1, 0, "Value", bgcolor = neutColorInput)

int period = masStartInput
for i = 1 to masQtyInput
    // ————— Call MAs on each bar.
    float ma = ta.sma(close, period)
    // ————— Only execute table code on last bar.
    if barstate.islast
        // Period in left column.
        table.cell(panel, 0, i, str.tostring(period), bgcolor = neutColorInput)
        // If MA is between the open and close, use neutral color. If close is lower/higher than MA, use bull/bear color.
        bgColor = close > ma ? open < ma ? neutColorInput : bullColorInput : open > ma ? neutColorInput : bearColorInput
        // MA value in right column.
        table.cell(panel, 1, i, str.tostring(ma, format.mintick), text_color = color.black, bgcolor = bgColor)
    period += masStepInput
```